# KeyDown Event not Firing in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, keydown

I am using WPF and VB.Net as Coding Language.

When I press any keys, on some keys like all alphabetical keys keyDown Event Fires nicely, But If I use arrow keys then keyDown event Does not Fire. On WPF I don't know how to do it. There was same problem in winForms too. But there was KeyPress event which worked perfectly.

I have searched on google but every where I got the same answer.

```
this.KeyPreview = True;
```

But I am using VB.Net. I cant find any `this` object in VB.Net

Comment: `this` is a C# term.  Try `Me` instead and drop the semi-colon.

Comment: Ya I know but what is equivalent to that in vb. I mean what do you mean by `this`

Comment: `this` is referencing itself.  For instance, if you're in a class that has a property, it can be accessed as `this.MyProperty` or just `MyProperty`

Comment: So If I have focus on textbox named `txt` then `this` means `txt`? or `this` means `me`?

Comment: MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Share your code please and we can point where you're going wrong.

Comment: Solved it. Used PreviewKeyDown Event instead of KeyDown Event

Comment: I was going to tell you that Textbox swallows keydown event for special keys like arrows, ctrl, alt, etc. Because it does special things with those keys.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is that some inner control in the visual tree capture the event when the arrows key are pressed. In this case you should listen the handled events to. The code below solve it, but it is in C#, you should adapt it:

```
visualObjetToCaptureKey.AddHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent,
            new KeyEventHandler((sender,e)=>{
                                                   //event handler
                                                  }), 
                                                     true);
```

In the event handler you should put what you want to execute. Also you can set a method to handle the event. Hope it works...

Comment: Thanks for replying. But my problem is solved. See the last second comment in question.